# Does ggplot2 exclude some data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, errorbar

I want to create some basic grouped barplots with ggplot2 but it seems to exclude some data. If I review my input data everything is there, but some bars are missing and it is also messing with the error bars. I tried to convert into multiple variable types, regrouped, loaded again, saved everything in .csv and loaded all new... I just don't know what is wrong.

Here is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)

limits <- aes(ymax = DataCm$mean + DataCm$sd,
          ymin = DataCm$mean - DataCm$sd)


p <- ggplot(data = DataCm, aes(x = factor(DataCm$Zeit), y = factor(DataCm$mean)
           ) )

p + geom_bar(stat = "identity",
         position = position_dodge(0.9),fill =DataCm$group) +
  geom_errorbar(limits, position = position_dodge(0.9),
            width = 0.25) +
  labs(x = "Time [min]", y = "Individuals per foodsource")
```

This is DataCm:

```
  Zeit mean        sd group
1    30  0.1 0.3162278     1
2    60  0.0 0.0000000     2
3    90  0.1 0.3162278     3
4   120  0.0 0.0000000     4
5   150  0.1 0.3162278     5
6   180  0.1 0.3162278     6
7   240  0.3 0.6749486     1
8   300  0.3 0.6749486     2
9   360  0.3 0.6749486     3
10   30  0.1 0.3162278     4
11   60  0.1 0.3162278     5
12   90  0.2 0.4216370     6
13  120  0.3 0.4830459     1
14  150  0.3 0.4830459     2
15  180  0.4 0.5163978     3
16  240  0.3 0.4830459     4
17  300  0.4 0.5163978     5
18  360  0.4 0.5163978     6
19   30  1.2 1.1352924     1
20   60  1.8 1.6865481     2
21   90  2.2 2.0976177     3
22  120  2.2 2.0976177     4
23  150  2.0 1.8856181     5
24  180  2.3 1.9465068     6
25  240  2.4 2.0655911     1
26  300  2.1 1.8529256     2
27  360  2.0 2.1602469     3
28   30  0.2 0.4216370     4
29   60  0.1 0.3162278     5
30   90  0.1 0.3162278     6
31  120  0.1 0.3162278     1
32  150  0.0 0.0000000     2
33  180  0.1 0.3162278     3
34  240  0.1 0.3162278     4
35  300  0.1 0.3162278     5
36  360  0.1 0.3162278     6
37   30  1.3 1.5670212     1
38   60  1.5 1.5811388     2
39   90  1.5 1.7159384     3
40  120  1.5 1.9002924     4
41  150  1.9 2.1317703     5
42  180  1.9 2.1317703     6
43  240  2.2 2.3475756     1
44  300  2.4 2.3190036     2
45  360  2.2 2.1499354     3
46   30  2.1 2.1317703     4
47   60  3.0 2.2110832     5
48   90  3.3 2.1628171     6
49  120  3.2 2.1499354     1
50  150  3.4 2.6331224     2
51  180  3.5 2.4152295     3
52  240  3.7 2.6267851     4
53  300  3.7 2.4060110     5
54  360  3.8 2.6583203     6
```

The output is:
[image: Output]

Maybe you can help me. Thanks in advance!

Best wishes,
Benjamin

**Solved it:**
I reshaped everything in Excel and exported it another way. The group variable was also not the way I wanted it. Now it is fixed, but I can't really tell you why.

Comment: Can you be more specific re the errors you see? What exactly is different than expected?

Comment: For starters, there should not be any `DataCm$` within the ggplot term - the data object is defined in the first argument and the columns are then adressed directly.

Comment: @CMichael: Sure, I know that it was just another poor attempt of troubleshooting...@patrick: As you can see in the Output picture there are some bars missing (should be 6 for each time point) and the error bars are messed up.

Comment: show the figue instead of link

Answer (score 0):

Your data looks malformed. I guess you wanted to have 6 different `group` values for each time point, but now the `group` variable just loops over, and you have:

```
1    30  0.1 0.3162278     1
...
10   30  0.1 0.3162278     4
...
19   30  1.2 1.1352924     1
...
28   30  0.2 0.4216370     4
```

`geom_bar` then probably omits rows that have identical mean and time. Although I am not sure why it chooses to do so, you should solve the `group` problem first anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It was a step in the right direction but still didn't solve the problem. Now I reshaped everything in Excel and exported it an another way. It works! But I don't know why...